# Symfony Composer Generating autoload files

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I recently inherited a bunch of Symfony2 projects from a former colleague. I'm trying to get up to speed with them but without any documentation on specifically what he did I'm struggling to even get them up and going. At this point I've installed the vendors/bin via `composer install` but at the last minute I get the following error

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
PHP Warning:  require(/Users/[path to symfony project]/vendor/tobie/ua-parser/php/uaparser.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/[path to symfony project]/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 54
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/Users/[path to symfony project]/vendor/tobie/ua-parser/php/uaparser.php' (include_path='.:') in /Users/[path to symfony project]/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 54
Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap handling the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception



  [RuntimeException]                                     
  An error occurred when generating the bootstrap file.
```

As a note, I've confirmed I'm running the newest version of Composer.

Has anyone run into this before? I've been searching google for the past 2 days have yet to find a solution.

Thanks!

Comment: It seems that it's trying to load the `uaparser.php` file from the `php` directory while it is located in `php/bin`. Did you modify anything or are you using an older version of the composer.json file?

Comment: if vendor was already exists before you run composer, try removing the vendor folder and run install again.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasPotaire. I finally figured it out, by deleting the composer.lock file, adding in tobie/ua-parser in the require (not sure why it was missing) and fixing the path to my autoload (which was missing the bin/ like you said).

Comment: Now I'm getting a [InvalidArgumentException] Command "app" is not defined error when it's generating the bootstrap file. 

Any idea about this?